# What structure (dictionary) with limited memory usage in C# can I use?

Tags: c#, memory-management, dictionary

Tell me what library (preferably in pure .NET) can be used for the following problem. There is

```
 Dictionary < long, MyData >
```

dictionary contains several million items as a result of the consumption of 1-2 gigabytes of memory, depending on the filling MyData.

Want to find a data structure similar to Dictionary, but which I can specify the maximum size of memory consumption, and if the memory is over, the data which have not been accessed for a long time, goes to the hard disk.
If the object is requested by key and object is stored on the hard drive it should be loaded to the memory.

In general I am searching .NET library for key/value storage with such requirements.
1. I have to be able to specify the maximum RAM usage of the storage
2. It should use disk for swap.
2. It should be fast.

Comment: *1. I have to be able to specify the maximum RAM usage of the storage* Considering that in .NET it is **very** difficult to measure the memory used by an object (`MyData` in your case), this **very** difficult. Setting a maximum number of objects would be a little easier.

Comment: With several million objects you should probably be caching all of them (what if your user doesn't have 2gb of memory?). Look into a relational document-driven database like Mongo-DB, or even SQL servers like MySQL or SQLite. Not only will your memory usage be better, but look-ups will be more responsive for complicated queries. Don't try to keep huge data structures in memory.

Comment: @ddd Note that a possible solution could be manual compression: you use protobuf to serialize the data, you compress it and decompress it only when needed... (while keeping the `Dictionary<>`). It depends on the type of `MyData`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78811/discussion-on-question-by-dddd-what-structure-dictionary-with-limited-memory-u).

Comment: I faced a similar problem. Ended up resolving it via disk-caching on an SSD with sqlite as the data persistence layer, and facading the data through a provider class using an indexed property. Think I might have gotten better performance with BerkeleyDB in retrospect.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing built in to .NET that does everything you want in one pre-made package. However all the components of what you want are there you just need to bundle them together.

There are 3 pieces to what you want

> 1. "Want to find a data structure similar to Dictionary, but which I can specify the maximum size of memory consumption"
> 2. "if the memory is over, the data which have not been accessed for a long time, goes to the hard disk"
> 3. "If the object is requested by key and object is stored on the hard drive it should be loaded to the memory."

What you are describing is a memory cache that is backed by a persistent store.

The easiest way (without looking for a 3rd party library that does this already) is make a class that holds a [`MemoryCache`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx) where you can set the [`CacheMemoryLimit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.cachememorylimit(v=vs.110).aspx). This takes care of requirement #1.

When you add items to the cache you set [`CacheItemPolicy.RemovedCallback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.cacheitempolicy.removedcallback(v=vs.110).aspx) to a function that writes the item out to the disk (be it a database, or file, or whatever you need). This takes care of requirement #2.

When you try to receive items from the cache and the cache returns `null` (the item is not in the cache) you then look to that persistent storage and retrieve the value and put it back in the cache. This takes care of requirement 3.

Here is a (untested) quick example of it, `IPersistanceProvider` performs the logic of the saving and loading from the disk.

```
public interface IPersistanceProvider<TValue>
{
    void Save(string key, TValue value);
    TValue Load(string key);
}
public sealed class CustomCache<TValue> : IDisposable
    where TValue: class
{
    private readonly TimeSpan _slidingExpirationWindow;
    private readonly IPersistanceProvider<TValue> _persistanceProvider;
    private readonly MemoryCache _cache;

    /// <summary>
    /// A custom cache that writes items out to a IPersistanceProvider when the item is evicted from the cache.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="slidingExpirationWindow">The amount of time before the item is automatically evicted if it has not been accessed.</param>
    /// <param name="cacheMemoryLimitMegabytes">The maximum size the cache can be before it starts force evicting items.</param>
    /// <param name="persistanceProvider">The service that will save and load data to a persistent storage.</param>
    public CustomCache(TimeSpan slidingExpirationWindow, int cacheMemoryLimitMegabytes, IPersistanceProvider<TValue> persistanceProvider)
    {
        _slidingExpirationWindow = slidingExpirationWindow;
        _persistanceProvider = persistanceProvider;

        _cache = new MemoryCache("", new NameValueCollection { { "CacheMemoryLimitMegabytes", cacheMemoryLimitMegabytes.ToString("D") } });
    }

    public void SetItem(string key, TValue value)
    {
        if (key == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("key");

        if (value == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("value");

        SetCacheItem(key, value);
    }

    public TValue GetItem(string key)
    {
        if (key == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("key");

        var item = _cache.Get(key);
        if (item == null)
        {
            item = _persistanceProvider.Load(key);
            SetCacheItem(key, item);
        }

        return (TValue)item;
    }

    public void RemoveItem(string key)
    {
        if (key == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("key");

        _cache.Remove(key);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_cache != null)
        {
            _cache.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private void SetCacheItem(string key, object value)
    {
        var policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
        policy.RemovedCallback = RemovedCallback;
        policy.SlidingExpiration = _slidingExpirationWindow;

        _cache.Set(key, value, policy);
    }

    private void RemovedCallback(CacheEntryRemovedArguments arguments)
    {
        if (arguments.RemovedReason == CacheEntryRemovedReason.Removed)
            return;

        _persistanceProvider.Save(arguments.CacheItem.Key, (TValue)arguments.CacheItem.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a native .net solution to your problem of being able to store gigabytes of objects in memory and make them searchable, backedup to disk, and memory efficient.

But there are tools that due that.  The general concept that you are looking for is probably a Document DB (or NoSQL).

If you primary focus is to make things searchable, I have Lucene.Net in the past.  There are also lots of Key/Value pair tools out there (I haven't used any, but perhaps others can make their suggestions).

Comment: It will be good if some one will share their experience about using .net key value storages.

Comment: We did an extensive testing and came to conclusion that any out-of-process solution (like memcache) is still much slower than in-proc custom memory manager that does byte[] with ultra-efficient binary serialization. That is because if you use disk, you still need to ser/deser, while if you use large byte[] then everything is already in ram. Here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dz_7hukyejQ   and another one: https://youtu.be/IUBF2Ncvbbs

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Ill look into this do better understand the scenario that this is to be used.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working at 64 bits, you can probably have

2a. It should use disk for swap

2b. It should be fast.

for free ignoring the prerequisite. Windows **will** swap out unused blocks of memory, and then it will swap-in when they are loaded. So you could simply ignore memory use and let the Windows handle it through the Swap File. The only problem could be if your `MyData` is a "reference tree", where a "main" object is connected (references) to other objects. Every one of these sub-objects could be located in a different part of memory, so it could be swapped-in/swapped-out separately.

Note that as a simple alternative, you could try to use `protobuf` to serialize your `MyData`, then use `DeflateStream` to compress it in memory, keeping a `byte[]` instead of the original `MyData`... Clearly you would have to do the opposite when the data is required.

Comment: We do what you described but there is no need to use protobuf, as we do all of it transparently via a ultra-efficient SlimSerializer, we pre-allocate large byte[] segments and provide two apis: 1 memory manager, 2 the cache layer on top. At the end of the day, the memory manager keeps track on byte[] allocations and provides high-level methods of turning a .NET ref into a PilePointer struct which is 2 inetegers, you can later dereference Pilepointer into original .NET obejct

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are dealing with some problems that the `WeakReference` class was intended to solve. The `WeakReference` class does not directly deal with persisting objects, but depending on the details of your problem, a different set of requirements might work for you.

Assume each dictionary entry value refers to a class that can fulfill these roles:

1. Knows the time when the data was last accessed;
2. When the time is within a certain threshold, it refers to the remainder of the data with a strong reference (a regular reference);
3. When the time is outside a certain threshold, it writes the data to file and moves the data to a `WeakReference`.

Then you just need a way to trigger objects to check the time, perhaps on a background thread with low priority. The memory limit might take care of itself in this case, if you choose an appropriate time threshold.